# How to use split or join to split a tag links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In `users/_form.html.erb` there is a list of interests which are spaced out with a space, e.g. "comic superhero happy". When I save the user's interests they appear in the users/show.html.erb file as one long link as in the attached image.

How do I separate the a tag links?

I tried this code to split the the links but had no success:

```
<%= raw @user.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(" ") %>

>> @user.tag_list
=> ["comic superhero happy"]

trying to get this result:
>> @user.tag_list
=> ["comic" "superhero" "happy"]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the problem is that `@user.tag_list` returns a single string. Show the code for that method. Also, what does the view code that you showed put into the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tags =  @user.tag_list.split(" ").map do |t|
  link_to t, tag_path(t)
end
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to use `split(" ")`. Using `split` will do the same thing. This is in [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-split).